# Ruby On Rails - Improve Caching with Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, caching, serialization

Willing to reduce views rendering in my `AngularJS` app, I am following this [Fast JSON API tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/fast-json-apis-in-rails-with-key-based-caches-and).

In my `RoR` app, most loaded objects are `Patients`, `Posts` and `Comments`.

I have two kind of `users`: `patients` and `coaches`.

When logging in as a `coach`, the app loads all information about `patients`, `posts` and `comments`.

FYI:

```
Coach : has_many :patients, :posts
Post: has_many :comments
```

Here are my `Serializer` files:

```
## Coach Serializer ##
class CoachSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

cached
delegate :cache_key, to: :object

attributes: #some attributes
## In HealthCoach model: has_many :patients
##                       has_many :posts
end

## Patient Serializer ##
class PatientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

cached
delegate :cache_key, to: :object

attributes: #some attributes

end

## Post Serializer ##
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

cached
delegate :cache_key, to: :object

attributes: #some attributes

has_many :comments
## In Post model: has_many :comments
end

## Comment Serializer ##
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

cached
delegate :cache_key, to: :object

attributes: #some attributes

end
```

This improved `caching` and `rendering-time` in my app in both `production` and `development`. My problem is that `production` is still slowly rendering.

Is there a way to improve `caching` more than I did?

Also, is there a `tool` to evaluate `rendering-time` with and without `caching`? I am using the following `rails s | grep Views:` to check for rendering? It is a good way but I need to do the `maths` by myself.